# Transposing an irregular matrix without truncating it

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

I have a big matrix of 300x100 lines. The problem is that some rows have 99 columns instead of 100.

I tried as an example with zip:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]

print zip(*a)
print zip(*b)
```

But the resulting matrix is truncated to the lowest number of elements, so the result from the example above is:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Also tried with `numpy` and `transpose` and it's not transposing the matrix because it is not regular.

I need to transpose this big matrix and get a 100x300 matrix and avoid a truncated matrix. So, is there already any python function or module that would return the transpose without truncating it?

Comment: I'd fix whatever is producing the irregular "matrix".

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the advice, I will consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (in python 3.X `zip_longest`) with a `fillvalue` argument to fill the missed item :

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*b,fillvalue=0))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 0)]
```